# Manage to connect through the terminal, but not through the remote explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am coming from notepad, and am learning how to work with VS Code.

I am now trying to access my online repertory on the webserver.
I followed up the guide here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

I did manage to access my server through the terminal window.
(ssh user@domain + password).
When connecting, this shows in the log:

> "Linux infong-eu27 4.4.246-icpu-061 #2 SMP Thu Nov 26 10:58:41 UTC 2020 x86_64"

This tells me that it is working on Linux.

If I type "Ls", I can see my folders and navigate among them.
So far, so good!

Second phase: Connecting through the remote explorer.

**Step 1**:
I configured the ssh with the same credentials I used with the terminal.

**Step 2:**
I am opening the remote explorer, I can see my server's name. I right click on it and select "connect".

**Step 3:**
I am then asking to choose the system. I am picking Linux as shown earlier when connecting through the terminal.

**Step 4:** I am entering the same password I used before to connect in the terminal.

**Step 5:** Infinite loading, or a very long one till I get 2 notifications / errors:

- Could not fetch remote environment
- Failed to connect to the remote extension host (error time limit..)

That being said, it also says in the bottom left corner, in the "remote window", that I am connected. This does not seems right.

[image: connection messages]

Any chance someone could help?
I am frustrated because it connects in 1s using the terminal, but not in the remote explorer.

UPDATE:
I found this article on medium that paraphrases the official documentation.
https://medium.com/@sujaypillai/connect-to-your-remote-servers-from-visual-studio-code-eb5a5875e348
I managed, through Git bash, to create a ssh pair key, and managed to copy one on my server.
I then followed the instructions on how to set it up on VS Code successfully!
Now, when I try to connect, I am asked for my key pass:

[image: asking for key pass]

But, when I do: super long loading, and the same error message.
When I looked on my server with a sftp software, I see that VS did manage to connect as files were installed in a VS folder it created:

[image: installed files]

Answer (score 0):

This is reported in [issue 4415](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4415) (no answer) and [issue 4204](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4204)

The last one includes:

> This might be caused by our new automatic port forwarding feature which scans the remote OS for available ports in order to forward them locally ([microsoft/vscode#112843](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112843))

This is fixed by [PR 113342](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/113342), for the next 1.54 Feb. 2021 release. That bug is about setting `remote.autoForwardPorts` to false and... still seeing VSCode auto-forward ports!

Check on your server (while VSCode attempts to connect) if:

- the CPU is high
- if there are any services running on public port on said server

Comment: That does not solve the issue in all the cases.

Comment: @ShashwatSwain I would be interested in a new question illustrating the use case which remains *not* solved. I suspect that would be the occasion to open a new issue on the microsoft/vscode-remote-release project side.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by following the error logs from the remote ssh extension. I had to install libatomic1 on the remote server with

```
sudo apt-get install libatomic1
```